# Negotiating Recruiter fee in addition to raise for accepting counter offer

Tags: salary, job-offer, negotiation

Is it acceptable or appropriate to request the recruiter's fee in addition to your salary as a bonus when being offered a counter offer that you are 100% willing to turn down?

Say I get a job offer from Small Good Company B and I work at Evil Greedy Company A and both companies happen to have wonderful teams to work on (do not confuse the corporate centric names with the teams I work on/will work on). Evil Greedy Company A aren't willing to engage in a discussion on increasing my salary beyond inflation annually but I love working there. I know my colleagues and ex colleagues have received more market level rates so my salary is being systematically kept down as a business strategy. I have received a job offer at Small Good Company B that is €70k. Evil Greedy Company B pay me €55k (I know, I am exaggerating slightly about how evil they are) and they have found €15k under the mattress of the CEO's bed so they come and match the offer when I give them my notice. Now I have two offers for €70k at companies I love.

If I leave Evil Greedy Company A, they will have to run a recruitment program and eventually find a replacement and pay a recruiter (let's say a very very conservative 10% recruitment fee) and they hire someone, again conservatively, for €55k. I say conservative because the usual fee in my location is 15 to 30%. The fee for the recruiter is this scenario is €5500.

I would like to stay, but I don't have to stay. Is it acceptable or appropriate to request the, very conservative end of the spectrum (I'll even round it down to €5000), fee that would be payed to replace me, basically give it to me or give it to the recruiter? Again, I know the answer to this question can be subjective and vary from company to company but I am hoping for some precedence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it acceptable or appropriate to demand the recruiter's fee in addition to your salary as a bonus when being offered a counter offer that you are 100% willing to turn down?

Ask for, Sure. Demand? Maybe not. You can ask for whatever you want. Weather or not they will say yes is up to them. If you think they really want to keep you then you will have to decide if it is worth getting turned down or not.

That said if they did this to you over 6 years they will do it again. You may be better off going to a new company. After 6 years maybe its time to expand your resume. You may have more opportunities at company B or any other company for that matter.

From my experience I had a similar situation. I had worked at a company for 2 years and I was being grossly under paid for the work they had me doing. I mentioned to them I was looking for work elsewhere as I don't like to burn my brides and my management kept telling me to stay and wait a while. That things will work out if I stuck around. I really loved my team and job so I decided to give them to the end of the year and it all worked out for me. I got the promotion I was looking for and made a 32% pay raise.  When I got the job offer I asked for more than I thought the position was worth so I could negotiate a decent salary. I ended up getting what I asked for so I lucked out. But that said it could have just as easily gone bad.

It all comes down to weighing the risk. If you think they are willing to negotiate and you already have another job secured then go for it. But try not to "demand" anything. That can hurt negotiation :D.

If you love your job and team then maybe take the 75k and count your blessings. Is the risk worth it at that point? This is something only you can decide for yourself really.

Comment: Just some critiques: In this situation, it seems impossible to "ask for" rather than "demand," so probably not worth bringing up. Another point is that you don't have to change companies to expand your resume.

Comment: @Mars sometimes you do. Some people get stuck in a single position because management doesn't want to lose them. I have seen that happen often enough. But if your company and management do the right thing then yes you can expand your resume within the same company. I say "Ask for" as Demanding things often go badly. If it was that important to demand then I would start with asking and move on to demanding but only if its an absolute must.

Comment: I know what you meant between demand and ask-for, but i don't think any phrasing can change how the company will interpret it. "So... if we don't give them this money, they're going to take the other offer, right? They're giving us an ultimatum"

Comment: I also think you can and should expand your resume, even in the same position. Theres no reason to not get new qualifications, or list new projects, or list new accomplishments, etc. I'd suggest that if you had a long run at the same company, you break your resume into projects or years (or decades) to show that you weren't idly doing nothing. But other people here probably have better ideas for how to handle that kinda resume. Also, hi, pretty sure i just commented with you on another thread 2 seconds ago!

Comment: @Mars lol yes we have commented on another thread. True you can expand your resume within the same role over time. Maybe my working on this was less specific than I wanted. I was referring to expanding your employment history with a new set of skills in with a different company as in taking on a new role with different task. After 6 years a change of pace could be good for your skill set. But yes you are correct. Breaking down projects in a resume is also a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

No.

You cannot word your demand in this way, nor can you use this the logical rational for asking for more money. Also - the emotions visible at the time you phrased your question should not be apparent when you talk to each company.

The problem is that you're complaining about basic capitalism, Company B isn't "better" than Company A because they're paying more - they're just paying the current market rate. But that is now - you have no idea if in 6 years you'll still be on that same rate at Company B.

That you were disappointed at your pay situation is understandable, but from the POV of a company it's easier to just not match the pay demands until they have to. Which is what is happening now. Also, you're no longer in that situation, so it is really a time to be happy!

You can of course negotiate for more than 70K with either company - nobody will be surprised by this - and in fact it is the best thing to do. Go to company B, say that you've been offered the same amount at company A, and ask if they can increase their pay to help you make your mind up what to do next. Put it like this:

---

Hi company B, I'm really excited to start working on *thing* with you, I love your *reason for existence*. I've just been offered 70K at company B however, and of course having worked there for 6 years it is now a tough decision to change company. I was wondering if you could increase your salary offered by 20K?

---

And you should push back to Company A too - just tell them something like this:

---

Hi Company A,

I really appreciate your matching the offer with Company B. It is always a tough decision when choosing where to go, especially when offered the same rate. Is it possible to increase this by 20K to help keep me on?

---

But don't mention recruiter fees or anything else. Who knows, maybe the CEO loves internally recruiting for roles and would prefer you left, or their recruiter is on contract to replace you if you leave before 10 years or who knows what.

(Also, you should never accept the first offer you're given - I know you don't mention this, but you strike me as someone who just accepts the first offer. Nobody ever minds if people ask for more money.)

Answer (score 2):

I think Sierra Mountain Tech lays it out pretty well.  I’d like to more add some points for your consideration.

Projecting my own experiences and assumptions on your situation, I would ask for another 5-10K on top, expecting it will not be met.  Six years is pretty long in a role so moving on may not be a bad thing for your career anyway.  They would probably indicate they’ve already offered 15K.  The counterpoints are 1) that’s merely correcting the discount they’ve been receiving and 2) they are telling you that despite knowing your abilities and the six years of valuable knowledge about precisely what the company needs, they value you no more than a company that only knows your resume and a few hours of conversation with you.

Further consideration:

How do you know Company B is good?  The interview process helps, but unless you have friends working there or something, there’s still going to be a lot of things you can’t really know until you’re already “in the system.”  Sometimes a known evil is better than the unknowns.  Sometimes it is not.

What happens in coming years?  Is Company B likely or even able to keep up with market?  If you stay, will Company A consider you locked in until you force the issue again (fewer/lower raises than market, etc.)?  It’s surprising a large company met your offer simply because many have set rules of maximum raise percentages, entirely regardless of circumstance.  This may speak to Company A being more flexible than other evil large companies.

History won’t really matter to Company A.  If they’ve underpaid you 15K for six years, you might think they owe you 90K in some sense.  You’ll never see that money.  They will attempt to calculate whether it’s more expensive to pay you than replace you and also factor in some risk of others learning of your negotiation and demanding their own raises.  Your 15K + whatever could balloon into 100K for them.

Psychologically, can you get past the 90K?  Sometimes, something in a relationship (and work is a form of relationship) goes bad and there’s never quite a way to come to terms with it.  You may be fine with it.  But if not, staying on can just lead to that eating at you.

So long as you don’t hold Company A hostage in the negotiation, such as demanding because you’re on a critical project but after that project you’re more replaceable, odds are if they do accept your counter, that will be the end of it.  A common thread on this site, though, is that some companies may give in to demands in the short term then make you the first target for layoff once they are in a better position to deal with your leaving.

Comment: Nitpicky, but the 90K should probably be scaled down based on raises and inflation during that time. Also, to Company A, the new rate may be what they consider a minus/investment. Even more reason why the chance that they lock OP's salary for a while is high